# OpenCV using Eclipse with CDT

Tags: c++, opencv, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I was always using QtCreator for OpenCV but a new project started with a friend needs to be done with eclipse.

I did all things I usually do with QtCreator but I am facing a strange problem. Although I did set the include path (/home/opencv/include) when I try to compile I get errors for missing headers (i.e opencv2/core/core.hpp). In the project explorer under include tag the only headers appear are the ones in the first level of the included directory. This means that cdt does not include headers recursively.

Is this a bug or I have to include every single directory?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem, too. I think what you need to do is to include the path opencv/build/include, not opencv/include. That's where all the header files are.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I figured it out but I forgot to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem yesterday. It searched all around forums but nobody could answer me. Finally I realized that I was doing the include for the whole  project and including files for the project **is not the same** as **including** files for the **source file "source.cpp"** (for eclipse, because for VisualStudio it is the same).

[image]

So try to rightclick on the .cpp file and include the directories for it. Anyway, if you tell me which version of OpenCV you're using I can tell you more aspects of how to include files in case you keep having troubles.

I hope it helps. When you get errors about missing headers is always related to include. At least it happened to be like this in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If the include path in Eclipse is `/home/opencv/include` , we assume that inside this directory you have 2 folders: **opencv** and **opencv2**.

On your source code you must reference the headers as:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

Does that makes sense to you?

Nevertheless, there are several tutorials that can help you [configure Eclipse](http://www.jestinstoffel.com/?q=node/112).

Comment: Sure, this is a common mistake when starting to use opencv2. It could be this or could be what I said in my comment. I have had all kind of errors with opencv in eclipse and visualstudio, haha

Comment: Are you sure that the file `/home/opencv/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp` exists?

Comment: Yes, in the picture there are no such headers under OpenCV2, but there are under OpenCV. It looks like they were moved from one folder to the other. Try to check the whole process again, step by step.

Comment: @karlphillip I am sure it is there. I don't know why eclipse does not display them. That's why I am wondering about recursive inclusion.

Comment: @Jav_Rock I did it 3 times with the same result. Eclipse refuses to see the folders under opencv2.